# Unable to simply use tr to convert a tab-delimited-variable file to a comma-delimited-variable file

Tags: csv, tr

Regarding [this txt file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jrdywhjrgj5sxgr/goods.txt?dl=0), which is best described as a tab-delimited .txt file with empty lines between rows containing content:

One would think that running

`cat goods.txt | tr "\t" "," > output.csv` should cleanly convert the .txt file to .csv.

(as per [this Stack Overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43637987/9095603))

However, I am observing values and text shifting into the wrong columns:

[image]

And in other cases, numbers being split up between columns:

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm overlooking?  What is a correct way to achieve the file conversion so desired here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that originally said "50,000 PAGES", which explains your problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: ... use a tool that understands how to quote embedded delimiters, such as `csvformat -t goods.txt > goods.csv`

Comment: You make a , a delimiter but clearly already have , in the file. An(!) option could be to 1st remove all current ,'s  from the file. A 50,000 would then turn into 50000 not invoking  a delimiter with your tr action. But that depends on your data: that could remove other ,'s too that must not be removed.

Comment: I can't make any sense of it ether. So not surprised that the computer can't. I recommend that you do the first 3 or 4 lines manually, so that you get an understanding of the file.

Comment: Would you please give a extract of yout txt file (with anon datas if there are some) ? Some more informations are needed to understand, and eventually give it a try in order to help. (in the question)

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller)

```
mlr --t2c cat goods.txt >goods.csv
```

you will have this output https://gist.github.com/aborruso/fab6a48a390a9c54de55dece9141bea6

Is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The following csvkit utility converts the .txt to .csv file cleanly:

> csvformat -t goods.txt

Credit goes to reg at [Whirlpool forums](https://whrl.pl/RfR491).

More about csvformat [here](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/scripts/csvformat.html) (converts a CSV file to a custom output format).

Also note, as per the [csvkit manual](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/scripts/csvclean.html):

===========

Note that every csvkit tool does the following:

- removes optional quote characters, unless the –quoting (-u) option is
  set to change this behavior
- changes the field delimiter to a comma,
  if the input delimiter is set with the –delimiter (-d) or –tabs (-t)
  options
- changes the record delimiter to a line feed
- changes the quote
  character to a double-quotation mark, if the character is set with
  the –quotechar (-q) option
- changes the character encoding to UTF-8,
  if the input encoding is set with the –encoding (-e) option

===========